# clion.sh does not exist

Tags: c++, unreal-5

I have Unreal Engine in Linux launched with `./UnrealEditor`

This file here `Linux_Unreal_Engine_5.3.0/Engine/Plugins/Developer/CLionSourceCodeAccess/Source/CLionSourceCodeAccess/Private/CLionSourceCodeAccessor.cpp` contains a default path for CLion which is  `/opt/clion/bin/clion.sh` but mine is somewhere else in `snap/`.

I used to just write `clion` in the terminal under `snap/` and CLion get started.

so I wanted to modify that c++ file but I do not have clion.sh, as I said I just started it with `clion`.

So I changed it to `/home/$USER/snap/clion`

When I launched Unreal Engine 5.2 and tried to open CLion from the  menu. I still cannot launch CLion.

Can someone help with this?